# How to Calling Services in Asp.Net-Mvc with ajax of star rating?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web-services, json.net, asp.net-ajax

Hi i had a problem to calling services of star rating in Asp.Net-mvc with ajax in 
view.
My problem is when checkbox of 5 star rating click then display all the data according to rating.Simarlly 4,3,2,1 rating also
What is sample code ? This is my Code.
    Code of View:-

```
@model IEnumerable<insertingapi.Controllers.HotelResult>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "About";
}

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js">
</script>

<script>
 $(document).ready(function () {
       $('#rating-5').click(function () {
       alert($('#rating-5').attr("value"));
       var fe = $('#rating-5').val();
       alert(fe);

       $.ajax({   
               url: '/Home/About',
               //contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
               type: 'POST',
               data: { ger: $('#rating-5').attr("value") },
               dataType: 'json',
               success: function (result)
               {
                    alert(result);
                    console.log(result);

                },
                error: function (status)
                {
                    alert(status);
                }
            });
       });
});
```

```
<div class="widget-sidebar start-rating-sidebar">
<h4 class="title-sidebar">Star rating</h4>
<ul class="widget-rate">
    <li>
     <div class="radio-checkbox">
            <input id="rating-5" type="checkbox" class="checkbox" value="5">
            <label for="rating-5"></label>
     </div>
     <div class="group-star"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></i> <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></i> <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></i> <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></i> <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></i></div>5 Stars <span>12</span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="radio-checkbox">
            <input id="rating-4" type="checkbox" class="checkbox">
            <label for="rating-4"></label>
        </div>
        <div class="group-star"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></i> <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></i> <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></i> <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></i></div>4 Stars <span>12</span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="radio-checkbox">
            <input id="rating-3" type="checkbox" class="checkbox">
            <label for="rating-3"></label>
        </div>
        <div class="group-star"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></i> <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></i> <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></i></div>3 Stars <span>12</span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="radio-checkbox">
            <input id="rating-2" type="checkbox" class="checkbox">
            <label for="rating-2"></label>
        </div>
        <div class="group-star"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></i> <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></i></div>2 Stars <span>12</span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="radio-checkbox">
            <input id="rating-1" type="checkbox" class="checkbox">
            <label for="rating-1"></label>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Code of Controller:-

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult About(string gen)
{
     var Af = gen;
     return Json(Af,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
 }
```

These is code :- I want all data about Hotel that according to rating it means
 When Enduser Click The check box of rating .Display all the data related of that rating.

```
     HotelDescription ,
     HotelCategory ,
     HotelAddress ,
     HotelContactNo ,
     StarRating,
     HotelPicture ,
     HotelCode ,
     ResultIndex ,
     Price ,
```

Comment: Pl z try to Help me.I am waiting for instruction

Comment: Any body there to guide me.plz waiting for code instruction